# How do I groupby with one key column, using condition on 2nd column and adding third column separately for weekday and weekend?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has 3 columns. ID, Day Type (Monday = 0, Sunday = 6), and quantity.

I want to groupby in a way that for each 'Id' I would have 2 rows, one with aggregate quantity of weekdays (M-F) and one for weekend.

```
Id  Qty  DayType
B07 581  0
B07 1096 1
B07 1245 2
B07 1080 3
B07 856  4
B07 581  5
B07 1096 6
B08 1345 0
B08 1580 3
B08 816  4
```

Expected output

```
Id  Qty  DayType
B07 4858 0
B07 1677 1
B08 3741 0
```

The 0 in the DayType in the output indicates weekday and 1 indicates weekend.

Also, if you can suggest how to pivot it later, that will be even much helpful

```
id weekday weekend
B07 4858    1677
B08 3741    0
```

I found a few solutions to groupby based on a condition but in this condition there are two conditions which I cannot figure out how to implement. Thank you.

---

Based on the answer suggested by Ansev, I am getting following output -

```
Id  Weekdays  Weekend
B07     20817     3607
C03     22289     6569
F05     22807     6474
```

That is correct.

But when I try non-pivot format based on Ansev suggestion in the comment under his answer, I get this -

```
id        Qty        DayType
B07       20817       43
B07        3607       44
C03       22289       43
C03        6569       44
F05       22807       43
```

As you can see it is adding up DayType too. I expect 0 and 1 there to represent weekday and weekend. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal is to use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
To group differentiating the type of the day of the week, we must check when **`df['DayType']` is greater or equal than 5**, we should also differentiate for each `Id`.
Since `df['Day'Type'].ge(5)` returns `False` or `True`, we can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) / [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to replace `True` and `False` with `weekdays` and `weekend`

```
aggregate_df = (df.groupby(['Id',df['DayType'].ge(5).astype(int)])['Qty']
                  .sum().reset_index().reindex(columns = ['Id','Qty','DayType']))
print(aggregate_df)

    Id   Qty  DayType
0  B07  4858        0
1  B07  1677        1
2  B08  3741        0
```

---

Finally we use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
final_result = (aggregate_df.assign(DayType = aggregate_df['DayType'].map({0:'Weekdays', 
                                                                           1:'Weekend'}))
                            .pivot_table(columns='DayType',values = 'Qty',index='Id',fill_value=0)
                            .reset_index()
                            .rename_axis(columns=None))
print(final_result)

    Id  Weekdays  Weekend
0  B07      4858     1677
1  B08      3741        0
```

Comment: Thank you. I liked your solution but is there any way to modify your code to output the non-pivot format which I have mentioned in my post?

Comment: I think you want `aggregate_df.reset_index(level = [0,'Id'],drop=0)`. Tell me if you could consider accept my answer

Comment: I have accepted your answer. However, what you have suggested in comment is not working out. It is aggregating 'daytype' column values as well. How do I keep them 0 and 1 for weekday and weekend resp.?

Comment: I think `aggregate_df.reset_index(level = [0,'Id'],drop=0)` or `aggregate_df.reset_index(level = 'Id').reset_index(drop=True)` should work well. 
If this second method does not work, you could edit the question with the data frame you will get with this code and I can suggest a new solution. Thanks for accepting:)

Comment: I have edited the post. The given suggestion is not giving me the desired output. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm sorry it was clear what you meant, I edited the answer

Comment: The updated solution worked. Thanks Man. How do you people know so much? I must die.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['DayType'] = df['DayType'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x<5 else 1)
df = df.groupby(['Id','DayType'],as_index=False)['Qty'].sum()
df['DayType'] = df['DayType'].apply(lambda x: 'Weekday' if x==0 else 'Weekend')
df.pivot(index='Id',columns='DayType', values='Qty')
```

Output

```
    DayType Weekday Weekend
Id      
B07         4858.0  1677.0
B08         3741.0  NaN
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: The suggestion by ansev is more elegant and better performing by far, just showing how you might navigate through this problem with a more basic understanding of pandas

Comment: Try using ```np.where(...)``` instead of ```apply(...)``` won't change much in terms of premise of the basic-pandas-solution ;)